# PHP "Undefined index:" error on Dropdown post request

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down menu populated by a MYSQL table. Which I have included the id and the name of a Faculty. I want to post the selected item's id on drop down menu to the next page. Which is addstudent.php. The PHP code is as follows.

```
        <form action="addstudent.php" method="post">
        <div class="input-group">
            <?php
            echo '<select class="form-control" id="sel1">';
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo '<option value = "'.$row['faculty_id'].'">' . $row['name'] . '</option>';
            }
            echo '</select>';

            ?>
            <span class="input-group-btn ml-2">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add Student</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </form>
```

The code on Undefined index is on addstudent.php page. The code is as below

```
  if (isset($_POST['faculty_id'])) {
      $faculty_id = $_POST['faculty_id'];
  } else{
      echo "Something is wrong";
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the name attribute in your `select` element.

Add a `name` to the `select` element like this:

```
echo '<select class="form-control" id="sel1" name="faculty_id">';
```

You are getting the post request by using your form post method on second page. So use the name attribute on that page with `$_POST` super global with given name of the field: `$_POST['faculty_id']`

Comment: Thanks mate. It solved my problem :)

Comment: Glad to help you @tha07 :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
<form action="addstudent.php" method="post">
    <div class="input-group">
        <?php
        echo '<select class="form-control" id="sel1" name="faculty_id">';
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo '<option value = "'.$row['faculty_id'].'">' . $row['name'] . '</option>';
        }
        echo '</select>';

        ?>
        <span class="input-group-btn ml-2">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" name="addstudent" type="submit">Add Student</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

AND your php code has some errors check this one

```
if (isset($_POST['faculty_id'])) { // OR if(isset($_POST['addstudent']))
    $faculty_id = $_POST['faculty_id'];  // Here the name of select not the value
} else{
    echo "Something is wrong";
}
```

Comment: There was no error in his php. What you propose is just a different way to check for form submission. Personally, I think the better way is to use hidden inputs with a static name/value to check for. Relying on a button name and the submit dynamics is janky in the long run.

Comment: Yes there was.. He had not the name attribute in echo the select box and was looking the post of select's value

Comment: I repeat. None of his "PHP" was wrong for what he was doing. His only error was missing the `name` on the `select`. Which has nothing to do with php.

Comment: So <?php echo '<select class="form-control" id="sel1" name="faculty_id">';
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo '<option value = "'.$row['faculty_id'].'">' . $row['name'] . '</option>';
        }
        echo '</select>'; ?> is not php? Sorry then there was not error